# How to make a side bar with padding and margin with endless content?

Tags: css

I've been trying to create a right side bar with a padding of 12px and a margin to the left of 10px, with flexible content, like the sidebar's height will expand with the text in it, if it was to be increased.

Problem is, I can't use flexbox, nor flow, or display.

Any help would be really appreciated :)

This is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1azLec3d/

```
 side-bar {
  float: right;
  padding: 12px;
  width: 326px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background: lightblue;
```

[This is basically what I'm trying to achieve.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBjgD.png)

Comment: Please further present what you want to achieve either with some code or an image.

Comment: I've added the fiddle, I'm sorry, really new here, didn't know how to do this ^^;

Comment: @LeanCuisine You normally get a guideline in your text editor before posting a question :)

Comment: @Helenesh you're right haha, it's a mistake from my end :)

Comment: `Problem is, I can't use flexbox, nor flow, or display.`--> so what you can use?

Comment: It's for a course, them the rules :')

Comment: @LeanCuisine Please see my provided answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use flexbox, I would do it with traditional `float: left` with padding and negative margin trick to stretch the shortest column to be the same height as its sibling. See snippet below for demonstration:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.head {
  background: teal;
  padding: 12px;
}

.sub-container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.main-content,
.side-bar {
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 12px;
  background: yellow;
  padding-bottom: 9999px;
  margin-bottom: -9987px; /* 12px less than padding-bottom since you want 12px padding bot */
}

.side-bar {
  width: 40%;
  background: pink;

}

.footer {
  background: green;
  padding: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">

      <div class="head">
        <h1>Zombie ipsums</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="sub-container">
        <div class="main-content">

          <h2>Mindless</h2>
          <p>Whyt zomby Ut fames after death cerebro virus enim carnis grusome, viscera et organa viventium.
          </p>

        </div>

        <div class="side-bar">
          <h2>Lucio</h2>
          <p>Zombie ipsum reversus ab viral inferno, nam rick grimes malum cerebro. De carne lumbering animata corpora quaeritis. Summus brains sit​​, morbo vel maleficia? De apocalypsi gorger omero undead survivor dictum mauris. Hi mindless mortuis soulless
            creaturas, imo evil stalking monstra adventus resi dentevil vultus comedat cerebella viventium. Qui animated corpse, cricket bat max brucks terribilem incessu zomby. The voodoo sacerdos flesh eater, suscitat mortuos comedere carnem virus.
            Zonbi tattered for solum oculi eorum defunctis go lum cerebro. Nescio brains an Undead zombies. Sicut malus putrid voodoo horror. Nigh tofth eliv ingdead.
          </p>

        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="footer">
        <h2>Hi mindless mortuis soulless creaturas</h2>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: I can't check it right now, but I'll do that in a bit, thank you so much <3

Comment: Best of luck. Don't forget to mark as answer if it solves your issue to help future searchers find more easily.